# iOS Swipe gesture for sliding between different Views in the same ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using XCode to develop an application for the iOS platform but have had trouble finding a way to display different contents (like **"ProfileImage", "User Description"**, etc) in the same ViewController. I would like to show such contents like you do in the **"Twitter"** app, in which you can slide between your "profile image" and your "description" by swiping to the left or to the right in the same ViewController.

I already know how to use a **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** to view different images inside a UIImageView, so I was wondering if there was a way to do such thing with different Objects such as passing from a **"UIScrollView"** to a **"UIImageView"** and viceversa.

Thank you in advance and please excuse my poor english.

Comment: Have you tried UIPageViewController? I believe it contains all the functionality you require.

Comment: Scroll view with paging enabled?

Comment: I solved my problem using the scrollView with paging. Thank  you

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for. After some research and testing this is what I came up with

https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers

Enjoy